# How to read data from a structural text file

Tags: r, amazon-s3, filtering, metadata, data-extraction

This dataset involves product metadata information from Amazon.

**The data looks something like this:**

```
Id:   0
ASIN: 0771044445
  discontinued product
        
Id:   1
ASIN: 0827229534
 title: Patterns of Preaching: A Sermon Sampler
 group: Book
 salesrank: 396585
 similar: 5  0804215715  156101074X  0687023955  0687074231  082721619X
 categories: 2
                       
Id:   2
ASIN: 0738700797
 title: Candlemas: Feast of Flames
 group: Book
 salesrank: 168596
 similar: 5  0738700827  1567184960  1567182836  0738700525  0738700940
 categories: 2
```

How do I import this txt.gz file and only want to extract information related to "Id:" and "group:"? However, if each chunk (the chunk between 2 blank lines) contains "discontinued product", I do not want any information from that chunk at all.

Comment: There are multiple way to do this but it is not something you load a package and call a function that can solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution to read your text. The `temp.txt` in the document contain the text you shared. You can replace the line with the a proper code to access the text file from S3.

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(tidyr)

text <- read_lines("temp.txt")
df <- tibble(text = text[text!=""])
# split text using the colon
df %>%
  # separate text into two columns
  separate(col = text, into = c("variable", "value"), sep = ":",
           extra = "merge", fill = "right") %>%
  mutate(
    # remove extra space from value column
    value = trimws(value), 
    # add value to discontinued product for later usage
    value = if_else(variable == "discontinued product", "TRUE", value),
    # create index_book column base on Id row
    index_book = cumsum(variable == "Id")) %>%
  # using the index_book to assign the Id to all row with same index
  group_by(index_book) %>%
  mutate(book_id = as.numeric(value[variable == "Id"])) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  # remove index_book column and rows with variable Id
  select(-index_book) %>%
  filter(variable != "Id") %>%
  # Convert data into wide format
  pivot_wider(id_cols = book_id, names_from = variable, values_from = value) %>%
  # filter discontinued product
  filter(is.na(`discontinued product`))
```

Here is the output of the code

[image: Result with filted discontinued product]

Comment: Yes initially I assumed there would be a function to read it but I realized that the format of the data is not in the cleanest way. Thank you very much for your help, it works well!